# How to get side drawer to close when clicking on link

Tags: reactjs

I have a navbar component that opens a side drawer when clicking the burger menu on a mobile device. But when I click a link it goes to the 'page' but the side drawer does not close.

Do I have to add a click event to every link to change the toggle state to false? That seems like the wrong, long winded approach.

```
const NavBar = (props) => {
  const [toggle, setToggled] = useState(false);

  const toggleTrueFalse = () => setToggled(!toggle);

  return (
    <nav>
      <div className="logo">
        <h4>The nav</h4>
      </div>
      <ul className={toggle ? "nav-links nav-active" : "nav-links"}>
        <li>
          <Link to="/" activeclassname="active">
            Home
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/faq" activeclassname="active">
            FAQ
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/contact" activeclassname="active">
            Contact us
          </Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div
        className={toggle ? "burger linetoggle" : "burger"}
        onClick={toggleTrueFalse}
      >
        <div className="line1"></div>
        <div className="line2"></div>
        <div className="line3"></div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default NavBar;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can have link array and map it :

```js
const links = []

\\in render
links.map((link,index)=>{
    return(<li key=index onclick={toggleTrueFalse}> 
        <Link to={link.to} activeclassname="active">
            {link.txt}
         </Link>
    </li>)
}
```